# Output PostgreSQL enum types

Tags: schemacrawler

I have some custom enum types (e.g. `CREATE TYPE speedType AS ENUM ('kph', 'mph', 'mps');`) in a PostgreSQL DB. Can I output that with the Schemacrawler command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

Enums types are supported as first-class schema metadata objects for PostgreSQL and MySQL, and displayed in the output since SchemaCrawler 16.4.1.

Sualeh Fatehi,
[SchemaCrawler](http://www.schemacrawler.com/)